# How to overflow IMG on the left side of container? CSS

Tags: css

I looked all over the internet for a solution to this problem, but I couldn't find a solution that fit my case. I am trying to make an IMG overflow on the left side of its container instead of overflowing on the right. I tried adding `direction: rtl;` but it did not work. Here is the pic of what I'm dealing with:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyxiY.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Is it a background image or just an image?

Comment: position relative on container and absolute on image .. and right:0 to image

Comment: just an image yeah

Comment: Dude just have patience the solution will come in good time. In fact it may never go away

Answer (score 0):

A way, if you have information about your image height and width, is to set the image as a background and control its left value. You will need to set a negative value to the background-position-x, such that the overflow will appear that it is starting from left.

```css
.img {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-position-x: -322px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyxiY.png);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="img"/>
</body>
```

Or another, if you would like to use the img tag.

```css
.img {
    position: relative;
    left: -144px;
}

.container{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container"><img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyxiY.png"/></div>
</body>
```